# Custom control to be used in another custom control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have a custom control that I need to use in another custom control. I have written all code at server side (no HTML). Can anyone tell me how to write below line of code in code behind using `htmlTextWriter` and how to register this control or how to write custom control within another where html is written from code behind?

```
<cc2:test id="test1" runat="server" marqueedirection="left" marqueeheight="25"
            marqueewidth="725" ShowImage="False" ShowTitle="False" ShowUrlUnderLine="True"></cc2:test
```

Answer (score 2):

First, build a simple custom web control:

```
namespace My.Controls
{
    public class InnerControl : Control
    {
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("<h1>Inner Control</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

Then build your second web control that contains and renders the first:

```
namespace My.Controls
{
    public class OuterControl : Control
    {
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("<h1>Outer Control</h1>");
            InnerControl innerControl = new InnerControl();
            innerControl.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, register the control on your page, and display it:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="c" Namespace="My.Controls" %>
<c:OuterControl runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankx it works..
i was missing only one line--

innerControl.RenderControl(writer);